# scala REPL - scala is not installed

Tags: scala

I have installed sbt as told in following statements:

> 1. Download sbt from here: http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/sbt.tgz
> 2. Unpack the archive to a directory of your choice
> 3. Add the bin/ directory to the PATH environment variable. Open the file ~/.bashrc in an editor (create it if it doesn’t exist) and add the following line export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH

But, when I type scala in terminal, it says scala in not installed! Though, sbt -h works fine.
How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Maybe you should try at least to read http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Setup.html .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing a tool

Comment: Question lacks shown effort and minimum research. In a nutshell, you've installed sbt, but not scala itself. Consider [doc page on scala installation](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to run `sbt console`command to run scala REPL from sbt.